# Cucumber ignoring @BeforeEach annotation and giving NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

We are using the Cucumber-library for automating our user-story tests. The tests do run, but all of them fail because we get a lot of `NullPointer`-exceptions.

The reason for these `NullPointer`-exceptions is that Cucumber is ignoring our `@BeforeEach`-annotation we have placed above a function called `setUp()` where we define all our variables.

Consider for example `@Given("er is een lijst van bestellingen")` at line 56. The `assertEqual`-function fails because our list `bestellingen` has zero items. However we've added those items in our `setUp()` function...

We really have no clue on how to use this library properly and the docs don't help us much further.

This is our relevant test-code:

```
package be.kdg.cucumber;

import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;


public class DeliDishStepDefs {
    private Bestellingen bestellingen = new Bestellingen();
    private Gerecht g1;
    private Gerecht g2;

    private Klant k1;
    private Klant k2;

    private Bestelling b1;
    private Bestelling b2;
    private Bestelling b3;

    private Koerier c1;

    int puntenKoerier;

    @BeforeEach
    @Before
    void setUp() {
        //System.out.println("lol");
        bestellingen = new Bestellingen();

        g1 = new Gerecht(1,"pizza calzone", 12.99);
        g2 = new Gerecht(2,"spaghetti bolognaise", 12.99);

        k1 = new Klant(1, "Jan De Rijke","kerkstraat 7");
        k2 = new Klant(2, "Piet Boedt", "kerkstraat 7");

        b1 = new Bestelling(1, g1, k1);
        b2 = new Bestelling(2, g1, k2);
        b3 = new Bestelling(3, g2, k1);

        bestellingen.add(b1);
        bestellingen.add(b2);
        bestellingen.add(b3);

        System.out.println("xxxx " + bestellingen.getSize());

        c1 = new Koerier(1, "Bert Fransens");
    }

    @Given("er is een lijst van bestellingen")
    public void er_is_een_lijst_van_bestellingen() {
        assertNotNull(bestellingen, "Er moet een lijst zijn van bestellingen");
        int size = bestellingen.getSize();
        assertEquals(3, size, "Er moeten 3 bestellingen zitten in de lijst");
    }

    @When("De koerier met id {int} kiest een bestelling met id {int}")
    public void de_koerier_met_id_kiest_een_bestelling_met_id(Integer int1, Integer int2) {

        if (c1.getId() == int1) {

            if (b1.getId() == int2) {

                c1.setActieveBestelling(b1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Then("De koerier met id {int} heeft een actieve bestelling met id {int}")
    public void de_koerier_met_id_heeft_een_actieve_bestelling_met_id(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        assertEquals(int1, c1.getId(), "De id van de koerier moet " + int1 + " zijn");
        assertEquals(int2, b1.getId(), "De id van de bestelling moet " + int2 + " zijn");
        assertNotNull(c1.getActieveBestelling(), "Er moet een actieve bestelling zijn");
    }

    @Given("Er is een actieve bestelling met id {int} bij de koerier met id {int}")
    public void er_is_een_actieve_bestelling_met_id_bij_de_koerier_met_id(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        assertEquals(int1, c1.getId(), "De id van de koerier moet " + int1 + " zijn");
        assertEquals(int2, c1.getActieveBestelling().getId(), "De actieve bestelling van de koerier" + int2 + " moet als id " + int1 + " hebben");
        assertNotNull(c1.getActieveBestelling(), "Er moet een actieve bestelling zijn");
    }

    @When("Bestelling met id {int} is afgehaald door de koerier met id {int}")
    public void bestelling_met_id_is_afgehaald_door_de_koerier_met_id(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        if (c1.getId() == int1) {
            if (b1.getId() == int2) {
                c1.getActieveBestelling().setStatus(BestellingStatus.AFGEHAALD);
            }
        }
    }

    @Then("Bestelling met id {int} heeft status afgehaald")
    public void bestelling_met_id_heeft_status_afgehaald(Integer int1) {
        assertEquals(int1, b1.getId(), "De id van de bestelling moet " + int1 + " zijn");
        assertEquals(c1.getActieveBestelling().getStatus(), BestellingStatus.AFGEHAALD, "De bestelling moet een status hebben van afgehaald");
    }

    @Given("Er is een actieve bestelling met id {int} bij de koerier met id {int} met status afgehaald")
    public void er_is_een_actieve_bestelling_met_id_bij_de_koerier_met_id_met_status_afgehaald(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        assertEquals(int2, c1.getId(), "De id van de koerier moet " + int2 + " zijn");
        assertEquals(int1, c1.getActieveBestelling().getId(), "De actieve bestelling van de koerier" + int2 + " moet als id " + int1 + " hebben");
        assertNotNull(c1.getActieveBestelling(), "Er moet een actieve bestelling zijn");
        assertEquals(c1.getActieveBestelling().getStatus(), BestellingStatus.AFGEHAALD, "De bestelling moet afgehaald zijn");
    }

    @When("Bestelling met id {int} wordt geleverd door koerier met id {int}")
    public void bestelling_met_id_wordt_geleverd_door_koerier_met_id(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        if (c1.getId() == int2) {
            if (b1.getId() == int1) {
                c1.getActieveBestelling().setStatus(BestellingStatus.GELEVERD);
            }
        }
    }

    @Then("Bestelling met id {int} heeft status geleverd")
    public void bestelling_met_id_heeft_status_geleverd(Integer int1) {
        assertEquals(int1, b1.getId(), "De id van de bestelling moet " + int1 + " zijn");
        assertEquals(c1.getActieveBestelling().getStatus(), BestellingStatus.GELEVERD, "De bestelling moet een status hebben van geleverd");
    }

    @And("De koerier met id {int} krijgt {int} punten")
    public void  de_koerier_met_id_krijgt_punten(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        if (c1. getId() == int1) {
            c1.addPunten(int2);
            c1.voltooiBestelling();
        }
    }

    @And("De koerier met id {int} zijn actieve bestelling met id {int} is verwijderd")
    public void de_koerier_met_id_zijn_actieve_bestelling_met_id_is_verwijderd(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        assertEquals(int1, c1.getId(), "De id van de koerier moet " + int1 + " zijn");
        assertNull(c1.getActieveBestelling(), "De actieve bestelling met id " + int2 + " van koer met id " + int1 + " moet null zijn");
    }

    @And("De koerier met id {int} heeft {int} voltooide bestelling")
    public void de_koerier_met_id_heeft_voltooide_bestelling(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        assertEquals(int1, c1.getId(), "De id van de koerier moet " + int1 + " zijn");
        int size = c1.getSizeBestellingen();
        assertEquals(int2, size, "Het aantal voltooide bestellingen moet " + int2 + " zijn");
    }

    @Given("De koerier met id {int} heeft een account")
    public void de_koerier_met_id_heeft_een_account(Integer int1) {
        assertEquals(int1, c1.getId(), "De koerier met deze id bestaat niet");
        throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
    }

    @When("De koerier met id {int} punten opvraagd")
    public void de_koerier_met_id_punten_opvraagd(Integer int1) {
        if (c1.getId() == int1) {
            puntenKoerier = c1.getPunten();
        }
    }


    @Then("Voor de koerier met id {int} worden er {int} punten getoond")
    public void voor_de_koerier_met_id_worden_er_punten_getoond(Integer int1, Integer int2) {
        assertEquals(int1, c1.getId(), "De id van de koerier moet " + int1 + " zijn");
        int aantalPunten = c1.getPunten();
        assertEquals(int2, aantalPunten, "Het aantal punten van koerier met id " + int1 + " moet " + int2 + " zijn");
    }
}
```

Full project on Git: https://gitlab.com/NielD/cucumber

Comment: Cucumber has it's own before hooks. They're different from the ones from JUnit.

Answer (score 1):

`org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach` is not supported by Cucumber.
Cucumber knows it's own @Before hooks.
For more information, check the [Cucumber documentation on Hooks](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?sbsearch=Hooks#hooks)